# How can I trigger Firefox memory cleanup from the terminal?

Tags: terminal, memory, firefox, ram, memory-leaks

Does anyone know how to initiate the garbage collection and memory reduction in Firefox (`about:memory` > Free memory > GC/CC/Minimize memory usage) from the terminal? This browser is using way to much RAM and I found that clicking on "Minimize memory usage" actually cuts the load by about 20-30%. Unfortunately, this doesn't last very long, but my idea is to create a Bash script and `cron` it.

Comment: Check this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-much-memory-or-cpu-resources Note that an extension could be the one eating up memory. I limited the number of concurrent (content) Firefox processes in very old computers and memory issues stopped.

Comment: Good question. It's frankly ridiculous these browsers don't manage their memory better by default.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani: Thx, unfortunately, it's the same with all extensions disabled and I already reduced the content process limit from 8 to 1...

Comment: @Time4Tea: Yeah, right? Isn't this also a security issue? Also, what reason would a browser have to use that much resources apart from (voluntary or involuntary) "distributed computing applications"? It feels like I'm permanently donating basically half of my PCs computing power to the browser xo

Comment: I run Firefox Nightly on a pretty old computer from 2008 and there are no memory issues. Could your expectations be wrong? I mean, the gap between the memory you think should be used and the one actually used? Do you experience memory issues? (since you are trying to manage memory directly). If you are running short on memory, swapping too much, etc, and you want to solve it you could ask a new question to see what happens to your particular Firefox instance. Please do state the browser's version and operating system.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani: Sry, I forgot...the browser version is 68.11.0esr running on an older Linux machine. And yes, I do experience memory issues, Firefox is slowing down the whole system. Regarding swapping...I have an SSD, which as I understand is faster than "regular" HDDs. Could the issue be solved by increasing swap settings and let Firefox use more swap instead of RAM?

Comment: 68esr ... ok, that explains it. The ESR is stable, but oldish. I very strongly recommend you switch to/test the normal release (at this time version 79).

Answer (score 3):

This can only be "automated" by opening a new tab and clicking the button which would be difficult to do but possible e.g. using `xdotool` or `xvkbd`, see:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/791793/how-can-i-automatically-open-an-url-in-firefox-and-click-on-a-specific-position

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026953/automatic-web-page-refresh-using-xdotool-not-sending-key-after-window-focus

If I were you, I'd instead use cgroups to limit Firefox RAM usage:

```
systemd-run --user -t -p MemoryMax=1500M firefox
```

This command works for me in Fedora 32.

---

Here's how you can run it from a shortcut:

```
cat firefox.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Firefox RAM Limited
Exec=systemd-run --user -t -p MemoryMax=1500M firefox
Icon=firefox
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```

Comment: Hi, the last option seems *very* interesting. Do I have to apply the `systemd-run` options to all Firefox "child processes" (e.g. `WebExtensions` and `Web Content`) or is it sufficient to limit the main process (`firefox-bin`)?

Comment: Also, will this option take care if there are multiple instances (e.g. there are usually 2-3 instances of WebExtensions)? And is the syntax for `systemd-run` case-sensitive, i.e. will it still work if I do `systemd-run --scope -p MemoryLimit=500M webextensions` for `WebExtensions`? Thx a lot ^-^

Comment: PS.: Btw, what would be the syntax to apply the options to multiple processes? Would this work: `systemd-run --scope -p MemoryLimit=200M firefox-bin MemoryLimit=200 WebExtensions MemoryLimit=500M Web Content` (and do I need to escape blank spaces)?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The systemd-run command will take care of all the child processes - they will all share the same RAM space.

Comment: Doing `systemd-run --scope -p MemoryHigh=500M /opt/firefox/firefox` opened a new Firefox window - is this setting permanent or do I have to open Firefox every time using the command?

Comment: Also, is this path correct? Doing just `systemd-run --scope -p MemoryHigh=500M firefox-bin` results in an error: `Failed to find executable firefox-bin: No such file or directory`. Which is strange, because the process name displayed in `gnome-system-monitor` is indeed `firefox-bin`. The "full" path was displayed when hovering with the cursor over the process name, but I'm not sure if it's the correct one

Comment: *is this setting permanent or do I have to open Firefox every time using the command?* You could create a shortcut (`.desktop` file in Linux terms) to run Firefox this way. No, this is *not* permanent - as soon as you close Firefox, any new instance run the usual way (i.e. without `systemd-run`) will be free to use as much RAM as possible.

Comment: You should run `firefox`, not `firefox-bin` I guess.

Comment: What is the difference? I just run Firefox from the icon in the panel

Comment: `systemd-run --scope -p MemoryLimit=1500M firefox` does not work, unfortunately, there seems to be something missing in this command...

Comment: Here's a command which works in Fedora 32:

`systemd-run --user -t -p MemoryMax=1500M firefox`

Comment: No, it's not permenant. You should create a shortcut to run Firefox this way.

Comment: What happens if the process attempts to write to more memory than the limit? Does Firefox try to minimize its usage automatically or does it just crash?

Comment: I'm not a programmer and I haven't tested it, so you could check it on your own and report your results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The command works well, but unfortunately Firefox does nothing to try and minimise usage, so it just crashes when it runs amok. I've set `MemoryMax=35G`, and it lasts for a few hours then crashes. I find I have to manually run `GC` periodically instead.